# Old mod_rewrite (htaccess) rule still applies

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, .htaccess

I had a rule in the .htaccess file in my root directory that said:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I've completely rewritten the file since then, and the rule is still being applied. I tried restarting the Apache server and the physical server with no luck.

I've also scoured the directory and there are no other .htaccess files in there or any subdirectories.

Does anyone know what might be causing something like this to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a behavior can be caused by [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). Try to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

I was racking my brain for hours trying to figure out what was going on.